# Stretching UserControl content to main window size WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a user control in WPF which has a WebBrowser control in it.I can't find a way how to stretch the WebBrowser to fill the size of the whole window.I tried all sort of tricks I found  here in SO but nothing helped.Here is my code so far :

```
<UserControl x:Class="TypeAppRelease.controls.HelpUserControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" Background="Aqua" 
       VerticalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" Loaded="UserControl_Loaded_1" Margin="0">
<Grid Name="parentGrid">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>

    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>

    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <WebBrowser Name="browser"  HorizontalAlignment="Center"   VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  />

    </Grid>
 </UserControl>
```

How can I set main window's width and height to be the dimensions of the child user control and of it's children?

Comment: are you wanting just the client area covered or the entire window including chrome?

Comment: I want the WebBrowser to fill the whole window.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the default behaviour will be for the `WebBrowser` to fill the `UserControl`; depending on how you then use your `UserControl`, it should expand to fill your window, if required.

Adding the `Source` property to the `WebBrowser` will give you a better idea of the space it's currently occupying.

This control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.UserControl1"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
     xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
     mc:Ignorable="d" Background="Aqua" Margin="0">
    <Grid Name="parentGrid">
        <WebBrowser Name="browser" Source="http://stackoverflow.com" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Should expand to fill this window:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <local:UserControl1 />
</Grid>
```

I've removed the row and column definitions, as there weren't yet any additional objects other than the `WebBrowser`, I'm assuming you'll stick some more in, otherwise you could just use the `WebBrowser` object directly in your `Window` (if you aren't intending on reusing the control).

N.B. you could remove the `Height` and `Width` properties from the `Window`, and set thiem in the `UserControl`, if you wanted it to define the size.